# How to use Selenium IDE testing tool?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am a beginner to testing and I have to use Selenium IDE in my project.

Can anyone help me in gaining the starting stuff, links containing detailed demo on Selenium, and how to run test cases using Selenium IDE tool?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.codediesel.com/php/selenium-ide-tutorial-part-1/) that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of good videos online as well, an example one  [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JM4GldTw_Cw)

Answer (score 0):

**[Here](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/search/label/selenium%20ide)** is very good material about selenium IDE. Described selenium IDE commands with proper practical examples.

Comment: I do agree with Strawberry.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link from where you can start up with selenium IDE and go on further
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp

It will be very helpful for you.